# django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakRef object leak for each request resulting in memory leak

Tags: django, memory-leaks, guppy

A django webapp is leaking memory. I have tried suggestions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory even though the app is not standalone.

I used guppy (by following this nice page: http://www.smira.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/heapy.html) to analyze the heap and I see a correlation between requests and a leak of django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakRef objects:

```
Partition of a set of 146642 objects. Total size = 10765760 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Referrers by Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  49064  33  2914412  27   2914412  27 types.CodeType
     1  21631  15   737184   7   3651596  34 tuple
     2  12883   9   727296   7   4378892  41 function
     3   5505   4   583728   5   4962620  46 dict of module
     4   3163   2   497232   5   5459852  51 type
     5   8192   6   481600   4   5941452  55 dict of type
     6    328   0   424000   4   6365452  59 function, module
     7    775   1   403000   4   6768452  63 django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakref
     8   1597   1   351728   3   7120180  66 function, tuple
     9   6015   4   270704   3   7390884  69 dict (no owner)
<1864 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
Reference Pattern by <[dict of] class>.
 0: _ --- [-] 775 (<referred by: <Nothing>> | <referred by: django.dispatch.s...
 1: a      [-] 774 django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakref: 0x84696cc...
 2: aa ---- [-] 1549 tuple: 0x846908c*1, 0x846910c*2, 0x846920c*1...
 3: a3       [-] 774 function: django.dispatch.saferef.remove...
 4: a4 ------ [-] 1548 __builtin__.weakref: 0x847539c, 0x8475a04, 0x8475b44...
 5: a5         [-] 774 dict of django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakref: 0x...
 6: a6 -------- [^ 1] 774 django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakref: 0x84696...
 7: aab      [-] 3 list: 0xb6e7156cL*1, 0xb6e7168cL*773, 0xb701684cL*2
 8: aaba ---- [-] 3 dict of django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal: 0xb6ee1c6cL...
 9: aabaa      [-] 3 django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal: 0xb6ee1c6cL...
<Type e.g. '_.more' for more.>
10: aaba3 ----- [S] 3 dict of module: ..models, ..signals, ..signals
11: aabaab      [-] 3 types.MethodType: <django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal at...
12: aabaaba ---- [-] 2 list: 0xa12888c*1, 0xa13896c*1
13: aabaabaa      [-] 2 dict of django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakref: 0...
14: aabaaba3 ----- [-] 2 django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakref: 0x9e9f46...
15: aabaaba4        [-] 5 tuple: 0xa15154c*1, 0xa15186c*2, 0xa1531ac*2...
16: aabaaba5 ------- [^ 7] 3 list: 0xb6e7156cL*1, 0xb6e7168cL*773...
17: aabaaba4b        [-] 2 function: django.dispatch.saferef.remove...
18: aabaaba4ba ------ [-] 4 __builtin__.weakref: 0x98e90cc, 0x98e9734...
19: aabaaba4baa        [^ 13] 2 dict of django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWe...
```

Note that django.dispatch.saferef.BoundMethodWeakref goes up in count(775 here) with each request.

I am kind of new to django, but something that I think is done differently in this app is that a reference to an object and a flag are added to each request object in process_request using a custom middleware class. I am not sure if the reference is causing django to not free up the request's resources somehow.

Here is the code tagging on the reference and the flag:

```
class ApplianceMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
    request.__class__.appliance = get_appliance()
    # do heap analysis across requests to check for memory leaks - heap
    # size across requests should be constant
    heap_analysis.analyse()

    request.__class__.from_int_if = False

    # Continue processing
    return None
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? If it is the reference being added to the request that is causing this, where can I clean up? Maybe by keeping a reference to the request object and deleting the reference to the appliance object when processing the next request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there were signal handlers being registered for request_finish, post_save, and post_modify. They were getting 'connected' for each request and they were sticking around after. A disconnect when handling the signal solved the memory leak.

The clue for it being related to signals was in the heapy heap info. e.g.:

```
aabaa      [-] 3 django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal: 0xb6ee1c6cL...
10: aaba3 ----- [S] 3 dict of module: ..models, ..signals, ..signals
```